# How to increase spacing of uppercase subscript

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

In one equation, I am changing my notation from the one on the left to the one on the right, which uses a right subscript. Especially compared to the initial version, the spacing for the subscript does not look good to me: it's too high and too close to the letter. It's also unbalanced compared to the superscript. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
(\bm{^{E}_{I}q})
(\bm{^{E}q_{I}}) 
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force it in one of several ways.  One way is to insert a strut of the right height in the subscript, to lower the rest.  Another is to insert a phantom superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
(\bm{^{E}_{I}q})
(\bm{^{E}q_{\rule{0pt}{6pt}I}}) 
(\bm{^{E}q_{I}^{\vphantom{E}}}) 
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there an advantage to using ^{\vphantom{E} compared to just ^{}?

Comment: @user284958 In this case, no it would not make a difference, since they share the same depth (0pt), If you did `\vphantom{q}`, you would see the `I` drop a little more.